# jQuery .on('click') even on a dynamically loaded page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a story uploading system on my webpage, which uploads stories in a specified folder, and from that it lists their content to the webpage. I split the text, so only 300 chars are shown of the text, and when the user clicks it the rest is shown.

This one lists it:

```
<?php foreach($dataArray as $data) { ?>
    <div class="visible">
        <?php echo $data[0] . "<br/><center><a href='#' class='story_show'>Teljes Történet</a></center>";  ?>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <?php echo $data[1]; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.hidden').css('display', 'none');
$('.visible').click(function () {

    $('.hidden').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

This page(`tortenetek.php`) is loaded via Ajax to the main page (`blog.php`). I included jQuery in `blog.php` like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stilus.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tinybox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ajax.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../js/lightbox.js"></script>
                <script src="../js/story.js"></script>
```

`Story.js` is the script file I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly then you need to take advantage of event delegation, by changing your `.click()` call to a `.on()` call, and passing a selector matching an ancestor element that is always in the DOM:

```
$('#someAncestor').on('click', '.visible', function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

Notice the change in the event handler function to use `this` and `.next()`. The way you currently have it will show *all* `.hidden` elements when you click on *any* `.visible` element.

`#someAncestor` needs to be an element that is present in the DOM at the time the code is executed. This works because most DOM events bubble up from the element on which they originate (the target) through the tree. You can capture that event at any ancestor element.

Comment: @trisztann - What is the problem now? What happens? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE for this, it doesn't show any syntax errors(it checks jQuery too), nor any error is present in the console. The page i'm working on is ajaxed, maybe it's an interference? I click the link - or any element - and the .hidden div doesn't appear. That's it basically.

Comment: @trisztann - Make sure the jQuery is wrapped in a DOM ready event handler e.g. `$(function() { /* Code here */ });`

Comment: I made the visible div a link, clicking it will show the hidden div. This is the php: <?php echo "<a href='#teljestortenet' id='ancestor'>$data[0]</a>" ?>  ... And this is the jQuery:  $('#ancestor').on('click', '.visible', function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').css('display', 'inline');
});